Needs some assistance in the sidebar closing
I am working on a Sidebar with Next.js, Tailwindcss, Shadcn-ui and i have written almost the same logic for opening the drawer if i click on a Sidebar icon. But i want to close the sidebar if i click again on the sidebar icon but my current code is not working properly. Can someone please look into it and tell where i am doing wrong.
Here is my SidebarOptions component code:
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { sidebarData } from "@/constants/sidebarData";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  Tooltip,
  TooltipContent,
  TooltipProvider,
  TooltipTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/tooltip";
import { HelpCircle, LogOut } from "lucide-react";
import { GoHome } from "react-icons/go";

const SidebarOptions = ({ onLinkClick, user }) => {
  const [isSubmenuVisible, setIsSubmenuVisible] = useState(false);
  const [openSection, setOpenSection] = useState(null);
  const sidebarRef = useRef();

  const handleSectionClick = (section) => {
    const sectionData = dynamicSidebarData.find((sec) => sec.title === section);

    if (!sectionData || sectionData.links.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    if (openSection === section) {
      // Close the drawer if clicking on the same section
      setIsSubmenuVisible(false);
      setOpenSection(null);
    } else {
      // Open the drawer for a new section
      setOpenSection(section);
      setIsSubmenuVisible(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (sidebarRef.current && !sidebarRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setOpenSection(null);
      }
    };

    if (openSection) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [openSection]);

  // Dynamic path modification for the "Edit Public Profile" link
  const dynamicSidebarData = sidebarData.map((section) => {
    if (section.title === "Profile") {
      return {
        ...section,
        links: section.links.map((link) =>
          link.name === "Edit Public Profile"
            ? {
                ...link,
                path: `/dashboard/profile/${user._id}`,
              }
            : link
        ),
      };
    }
    return section;
  });

  return (
    <TooltipProvider>
      <div className="flex h-screen">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-12 bg-white border-r">
          <div className="flex flex-col px-2 mb-2">
            <Tooltip className="bg-black text-white">
              <TooltipTrigger>
                <Link
                  href="/dashboard"
                  className="flex flex-col items-center mb-3 p-2 text-[#F6F6F6] hover:bg-[#DFEDEE] 
                rounded cursor-pointertransition-all duration-200 ease-in-out transform"
                >
                  <GoHome className="text-muted-foreground size-4" />
                </Link>
              </TooltipTrigger>
            </Tooltip>
            {dynamicSidebarData.map((section, sectionIndex) => (
              <Tooltip key={sectionIndex} className="bg-black text-white">
                <TooltipTrigger>
                  <div
                    className="flex flex-col items-center mb-3 p-2 text-[#F6F6F6] hover:bg-[#DFEDEE] rounded cursor-pointer
                                transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out transform"
                    onClick={() => handleSectionClick(section.title)}
                  >
                    {section.icon}
                  </div>
                </TooltipTrigger>
                <TooltipContent
                  side="right"
                  className="mr-2 bg-black text-white font-bold"
                >
                  <p>{section.title}</p>
                </TooltipContent>
              </Tooltip>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-36 py-4">
            <Tooltip className="bg-black text-white">
              <TooltipTrigger>
                <Link href="/help" legacyBehavior>
                  <a className="flex flex-col items-center mb-2 p-2 rounded">
                    <HelpCircle className="text-muted-foreground size-4" />
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </TooltipTrigger>
              <TooltipContent side="right" className="mr-2">
                <p className="">Help</p>
              </TooltipContent>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip className="bg-black text-white">
              <TooltipTrigger>
                <Link href="/logout" legacyBehavior>
                  <a className="flex flex-col items-center mb-6 p-2 rounded">
                    <LogOut className="text-rose-500 size-4" />
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </TooltipTrigger>
              <TooltipContent side="right" className="mr-2">
                <p className="">Logout</p>
              </TooltipContent>
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        </div>
        {openSection && (
          <div
            ref={sidebarRef}
            className={`absolute left-16 top-0 backdrop-blur-md bg-white/50 bg-white border-r p-4 w-[200px] z-[99999] h-full overflow-y-auto
                      transform transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out
                      ${
                        isSubmenuVisible
                          ? "translate-x-0 opacity-100"
                          : "-translate-x-full opacity-0"
                      }`}
          >
            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">{openSection}</h2>

            {dynamicSidebarData
              .find((section) => section.title === openSection)
              .links.map((link, linkIndex) => (
                <div
                  key={linkIndex}
                  className="flex items-center gap-2 my-2 p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 rounded cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (onLinkClick) {
                      onLinkClick(link.path);
                    }
                    setOpenSection(null);
                  }}
                >
                  <Link href={link.path} className="text-gray-700">
                    {link.name}
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </TooltipProvider>
  );
};

export default SidebarOptions;


